# Doubt in notation of minors of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am reading [Joydip Saha, Indranath Sengupta, Gaurab Tripathi, *Ideals of the form $I_1\left(XY\right)$*, Journal of Symbolic Computation **91**, March–April 2019, pp. 17--29](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2018.06.011) ([arXiv:1609.02765v7](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02765v7)).

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}
1&x_1& x_1^{2} \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^{2}\\
1&x_3&x_3^{2}  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$Y=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3\\
\end{pmatrix} $

Although it might seem to be a trivial problem but  I am not accustomed to such a notation of a matrix. Is my way of calculating it correct?
$$[13 \mid 12]y_2 +[13\mid13]y_3 = y_2x_3 - y_2x_1 + y_3x_3^2 - y_3x_1^2 $$
$$[23 \mid 12]y_2+[23\mid13]y_3 =y_2x_3 - y_2x_2 + y_3x_3^2 - y_3x_2^2$$

Comment: What is "it" in the sentence "my way of calculating it"?

Comment: I wanted to check whether $[13|12]y_2 + [13|13]y_3$ gives the polynomial that I have calculated

Comment: Context? Where did you come across this notation?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0747717118300762?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation used in the paper you are reading is not standard (I would say there is no standard notation for minors, although there are some schools that have their habits), and is not well explained in the paper (Section 3 item (ii) only defines minors of the form $\left[a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k \mid 1, 2, \ldots, k\right]$, but later uses minors of other forms).

My guess is that $\left[a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k \mid b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k\right]$ means the minor formed of the $a_i$-th rows (for all $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$) and of the $b_j$-th columns (for all $j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$) of some given matrix (which one? again, the paper is confusing here, but when there is only one matrix around there is no ambiguity).

With this guess, your computations are indeed correct.